# Light browser-side JavaScript library for ML image captioning

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to write a web plugin that will analyze a video (or more realistically some frames from a video) and output what happens on the video (what items there are, how many people there, where people are looking etc).

It should also be able to run on an "average" PC and not be too heavy at the cost of accuracy and work with pretrained models.

Ideally less than 30 MB.

Comment: What is wrong with tensorflow.js? Whether another library is better or worse really depends on your use case, so please explain more than "_give me some info_". Are you trying to run classification for instance? How many classes? Some example classes might help. What pre-trained model size is OK?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with tensorflow.js, i just want to look at different options, but can't really find anything. eventually I want to know something about what happens on the video (what items there are, how many people there, where people are looking etc) and based on that info make some predictions. Size of the model will be ofc as small as possible, but as far as I know somewhat optimal size should be less than 30 MB, so I am sticking to that  number for now

Comment: Thanks, the use case you describe is called "Image captioning" and it is indeed very different from classification. Better remove mentions of specific libraries, just let answers come.